# MediaPlayer.prepare() fails with a valid http link

Tags: android, http, streaming, media-player, mp4

I was trying to stream some videos: with 3gp everything works fine and smooth, but when I tried mp4 (I used several videos for tests, including this one, which should definitely be good and valid - [commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4](http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4)), I got an exception.

I have an android 2.2 tablet for testing, is my problem because of this? Will mp4-via-http work on android 2.3 or newer? Or are there any specific for mp4 preparatory steps I don't know about? Now I just do the following:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    gMp=new MediaPlayer();
    gMp.setDisplay(hndlr);
    try {
        gMp.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4"));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        gMp.prepareAsync();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    gMp.start();
}
```

Here are my error logs:

```
I/ActivityManager(  107): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.video.mp/.VideoSharingViaMPActivity }    
I/ActivityManager(  107): Start proc com.video.mp for activity com.video.mp/.VideoSharingViaMPActivity: pid=746 uid=10055 gids={1015, 3003}    
D/dalvikvm(  746): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 576 objects / 46928 bytes in 37ms    
I/dalvikvm-heap(  746): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.549MB for 1000016-byte allocation    
D/dalvikvm(  746): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 170 objects / 8488 bytes in 44ms    
D/MediaPlayer(  746): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): Client(3) constructor    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): Create new client(3) from pid 746, url=http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4, connId=3    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): setDataSource(http://commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4)    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): player type = 1    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67):  create PVPlayer    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67):  setDataSource    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): [3] setVideoSurface(0x3cfd8)    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): [3] setAudioStreamType(3)    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): [3] prepareAsync    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): [3] notify (0x3b2f8, 3, 0, 0)    
I/PlayerDriver(   67): buffering (1)    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): [3] notify (0x3b2f8, 3, 1, 0)    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): [3] notify (0x3b2f8, 200, 1, 26)    
W/MediaPlayer(  746): info/warning (1, 26)    
E/PlayerDriver(   67): Command PLAYER_INIT completed with an error or info PVMFErrResource    
V/MediaPlayerService(   67): [3] notify (0x3b2f8, 100, 1, -17)    
W/PlayerDriver(   67): PVMFInfoErrorHandlingComplete    
E/MediaPlayer(  746): error (1, -17)    
W/System.err(  746): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1    
W/System.err(  746):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)    
W/System.err(  746):    at com.video.mp.VideoSharingViaMPActivity.surfaceCreated(VideoSharingViaMPActivity.java:146)
```

Comment: Please post the error information.

Comment: Edited the post and added some, it seems I misunderstood and it fails on prepare (or prepareAsync, I get the same results for both)

Comment: You shouldn't call `gMp.start()` right after prepareAsync, but you should add `MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener` via `gMp.setOnPreparedListener()`. In this listener it is time to start your Player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this: in your code you have link `http://www.commonsware.com/misc/test.mp4` while real link is without `www` (also, I checked with my browser, link with `www` doesn't exist).

Comment: Ouch. That would be reeally embarrassing. Lucky me, I have the link in my code without the www part, and still not working.

Comment: Oh whatever. I tried different encoding programs and found one that did the job fine. So the problem was with the file then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start()/reset() the Mediaplayer first. See the valid and invalid states here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#Valid_and_Invalid_States

Comment: Umm, it's already uninitialized, since I create a new instance, hence there's no reason to do reset() at all.

Comment: Umm, ok. My point was that either a start() or reset() might be necessary depending on the situation. Either way, you need place the call to start() before you call setDataSource(). At this point, though, you've completely modified your question so...